# AJAX in Laravel Blade ignoring div class

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm very new at AJAX JavaScript, and i got tast for filtering data in Laravel 10 without refresh using AJAX
but no luck yet.

This is the code for my blade view :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        const clickableElements = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable');
        // Fungsi untuk mengambil dan menampilkan data campaign berdasarkan kategori
        function filterCampaignByCategory(category) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/filter', // Sesuaikan dengan rute Anda
                data: { filter: category },
                success: function(data) {
                    var campaigns = data.campaigns;
                    var campaignList = $('#daftar_campaign');
                    campaignList.empty();

                    // Loop melalui data campaign dan tambahkan ke daftar
                    $.each(campaigns, function(key, campaign) {
                        campaignList.append(
                            '<div class="popular-causes__sinlge">' +
                            '<div class="popular-causes__img">' +
                            '<img height="300px" src="http://127.0.0.1:8001/storage/' + campaign.BannerCampaign + '" alt="">' +
                            '<div class="popular-causes__category">' +
                            '<p>' + campaign.KategoriCampaign + '</p>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="popular-causes__content" style="width: 370px">' +
                            '<div class="popular-causes__title" style="height: 100px">' +
                            '<h3><a href="campaign-details.html">' + campaign.NamaCampaign + '</a></h3>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="popular-causes__progress" style="height: 200px">' +
                            '<div class="bar">' +
                            '<div class="bar-inner count-bar" data-percent="' + campaign.percentageCompleted + '%">' +
                            '<div class="count-text">' + campaign.percentageCompleted + '%</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="popular-causes__goals">' +
                            '<p><span>' + campaign.HasilDonasiCampaign + '</span> Terkumpul</p>' +
                            '<p><span>' + campaign.TargetCampaign + '</span> Target</p>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        clickableElements.forEach(function(element) {
            element.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const value = element.getAttribute('data-value');
                filterCampaignByCategory(value);
            });
        });

        function sendGetRequest(value) {
            window.location.href = "/?filter=" + value;
        }

        // Tambahkan event listener untuk ikon kategori
        $('.category-icon').on('click', function() {
            var selectedCategory = $(this).data('category');
            filterCampaignByCategory(selectedCategory);
        });

        
        // Memuat semua campaign saat halaman pertama kali dimuat
         // Menggunakan '' untuk memuat semua campaign
    
    </script>

    <!--campaign Start-->
    <section class="popular-causes">
        <div class="container pb-5 mb-5">
            <div class="block-title text-left">
                <h4>Help the People</h4>
                <h3>Our Popular Campaigns</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="popular-causes__carousel owl-theme owl-carousel" id="daftar_campaign">
                        @foreach ($campaigns as $campaign)
                            <div class="popular-causes__sinlge">
                                <div class="popular-causes__img">
                                    <img height="300px" src="http://127.0.0.1:8001/storage/{{ $campaign->BannerCampaign }}"
                                        alt="">
                                    <div class="popular-causes__category">
                                        <p>{{ $campaign->KategoriCampaign }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="popular-causes__content" style="width: 370px">
                                    <div class="popular-causes__title" style="height: 100px">
                                        <h3><a href="campaign-details.html">{{ $campaign->NamaCampaign }}</a>
                                        </h3>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="popular-causes__progress" style="height: 200px">
                                        <div class="bar">
                                            <div class="bar-inner count-bar"
                                                data-percent="{{ $campaign->percentageCompleted }}%">
                                                <div class="count-text">{{ $campaign->percentageCompleted }}%</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="popular-causes__goals">
                                            <p><span>{{ $campaign->HasilDonasiCampaign }}</span> Terkumpul</p>
                                            <p><span>{{ $campaign->TargetCampaign }}</span> Target</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and this is the code for my controller :

```
public function filter(Request $request){
        $filter = $request->input('filter');

        if (empty($filter)) {
            $campaigns = Campaign::with('user')
                        ->select('NamaCampaign','UrlCampaign','KategoriCampaign','BannerCampaign','MulaiCampaign','AkhirCampaign','TargetCampaign','HasilDonasiCampaign')
                        ->where('Prioritas', 1)
                        ->where('Aktif', 1)
                        ->latest('idCampaign')
                        ->get();
        } else {
            $campaigns = Campaign::with('user')
                        ->select('NamaCampaign','UrlCampaign','KategoriCampaign','BannerCampaign','MulaiCampaign','AkhirCampaign','TargetCampaign','HasilDonasiCampaign')
                        ->where('KategoriCampaign', $filter)
                        ->where('Prioritas', 1)
                        ->where('Aktif', 1)
                        ->latest('idCampaign')
                        ->get();
        }
        
        return response()->json(['campaigns' => $campaigns]);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u183W.jpg)
this i the default page before filtering

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/893zn.png)
and this is after the filtering data, the filter work but upon investigation the Ajax is ignoring my
div class making it weird look :

```
<div class="popular-causes__carousel owl-theme owl-carousel" id="daftar_campaign">
```

I already tried many solutions and haven't found luck yet, I really love to see what or thoughts why this is happening.

Comment: Laravel actually provides a really clean way to return the rendered HTML from a `.blade.php` file as text, so you don't have to completely reconstruct it in Javascript. You can do something like `return response()->json(['html' => view('your-blade-file')->with(['campaigns' => $campaigns])->render()], 200);`, and you'd be able to do `$('#daftar_campaign').html(data.html)` instead of `.empty()` followed by multiple `.append()` calls. But, you'd need to have a separate `.blade.php` file for `<div class="popular-causes__carousel owl-theme owl-carousel" id="daftar_campaign"> ... </div>`

Comment: You don't have to send the original, I didn't see it in your question since it was scrolled down a bit. All good! And the reason `$('#daftar_campaign').html(data.html);` doesn't do anything is that `id="daftar_campaign"` is part of the HTML being returned. You need to move that `id="daftar_campaign"` to a div _above_ where you want to apply it, like `<div class="col-xl-12" id="daftar_campaign">`

Comment: Thanks! your method did somehing actualy https://imgur.com/7XsragE but it did render html inside html whichis kinda funny

Comment: Haha, so yeah, you've got the idea, but you'll need to tweak both your HTML and JS to get this working the same way. I'll write up a quick answer below to try and show you how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, move the HTML into a unique `.blade.php` file. Let's call it `campaigns.blade.php`, inside of `resources/views`:

```html
<div class="popular-causes__carousel owl-theme owl-carousel" id="daftar_campaign">
  @foreach($campaigns as $campaign)
    <div class="popular-causes__sinlge">
      <div class="popular-causes__img">
        <img height="300px" src="http://127.0.0.1:8001/storage/{{ $campaign->BannerCampaign }}" alt="" />
        <div class="popular-causes__category">
          <p>{{ $campaign->KategoriCampaign }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="popular-causes__content" style="width: 370px">
        <div class="popular-causes__title" style="height: 100px">
          <h3>
            <a href="campaign-details.html">{{ $campaign->NamaCampaign }}</a>
          </h3>    
        </div>
        <div class="popular-causes__progress" style="height: 200px">
          <div class="bar">
            <div class="bar-inner count-bar" data-percent="{{ $campaign->percentageCompleted }}%">
              <div class="count-text">{{ $campaign->percentageCompleted }}%</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="popular-causes__goals">
            <p>
              <span>{{ $campaign->HasilDonasiCampaign }}</span> Terkumpul
            </p>
            <p>
              <span>{{ $campaign->TargetCampaign }}</span> Target
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

In your existing `.blade.php` file, "include" this one:

```html
<section class="popular-causes">
  <div class="container pb-5 mb-5">
    <div class="block-title text-left">
      <h4>Help the People</h4>
      <h3>Our Popular Campaigns</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="campaignsContainer" class="col-xl-12">
        @include('campaigns', ['campaigns' => $campaigns])
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Notice how I added `id="campaignsContainer"` to the `<div>` immediately surrounding the `@include()` section. This is important for later.

Now, in your Controller, modify your `return` statement:

```php
public function filter(Request $request){
  $campaigns = Campaign::with('user') /* ... */ ->get();

  return response()->json(['html' => view('campaigns', ['campaigns' => $campaigns])->render()], 200);
}
```

Finally, modify your JS:

```js
function filterCampaignByCategory(category) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/filter',
    data: { filter: category },
    success: function(response) {
      $('#campaignsContainer').html(response.html);
    }
  });
}
```

The line `$('#campaignsContainer').html(response.html);` will take the returned HTML from the Controller, which is an exact duplicate of your existing HTML (since `@include('view', ...)` and `view('view', ...)` generate the same HTML) and overwrite it with the new `$campaigns` that are generated inside of the Controller.

And that should do it!

Answer (score 0):

base on your script try to comment or delete this line : campaignList.empty();